# iOS handle consecutive push notifications with sound

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm really sick of Apple Push Notification service.. but still, I wanna deal with it..

I have a VoIP app that receives incoming call push notifications.. It works fine except that when I have two consecutive incoming calls, the sound in both notifications will play together - like a double ringing effect... (my sound is a bit longer than a normal notification sound - the ring will last around 10s)

I see many chatting apps, if there are multiple messages coming in, the following messages will only show the alert message without the sound. I wanna know how can I achieve that. Is it handled on the server side or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't send multiple push messages together from your server. If you sent a ring 1s ago and your sound is 10 seconds long and your system is *still* ringing them on the first call, don't even send the second until you know what's happened with the first.

Same for other notifications. If you push multiple notifications together to the same device within say 15s of each other, send the first with sound on, send the rest with sound off.

Your server logic can and should deal with all this for the user. The client may not have a chance to deal with it.

Comment: are you experienced with push notification? if so, can you please take a look at another question I have post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645169/ios-best-practice-to-send-incoming-call-notifications-on-voip-app